# Filling matrix gaps in a GROUP BY result

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table that contains transactions that I now want to build a report on. I'm grouping by the hour, but would like to include 0 sums per hour if there were no transactions during that hour.

The following works for me:

```
SELECT
    gh,
    IFNULL(d.count, 0) AS `count`
FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_TIMESTAMP_ARRAY('2021-08-10 00:00:00', '2021-08-17 23:59:59', INTERVAL 1 HOUR)) as gh
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(DATI, HOUR) hour,
        COUNT(*) `count`
    FROM `transactions`
    WHERE DATE(DATI) >= "2021-08-10"
    AND PMP IS NOT NULL
    AND (QTY IS NULL OR QTY = 0)
    GROUP BY hour
    ORDER BY hour
) d ON d.hour = gh
ORDER BY gh
```

However, these sum the transactions over a set of sites, I would also like to get a report on a count per site so I'd have to `GROUP BY site_id` and select that column as well, but I don't have anything to join to in the original UNNEST select...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this should work:

```
SELECT
    gh,
    IFNULL(d.count, 0) AS `count`
FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_TIMESTAMP_ARRAY('2021-08-10 00:00:00', '2021-08-17 23:59:59', INTERVAL 1 HOUR)) as gh
CROSS JOIN (select distinct site_id from transactions) sites
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(DATI, HOUR) hour,
        site_id
        COUNT(*) `count`
    FROM `transactions`
    WHERE DATE(DATI) >= "2021-08-10"
    AND PMP IS NOT NULL
    AND (QTY IS NULL OR QTY = 0)
    GROUP BY hour
    ORDER BY hour
) d ON d.hour = gh
  AND d.site_id = sites.site_id
ORDER BY gh
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks! Didn't know about `CROSS JOIN`